# HTML2PDF ignores header margins

Tags: php, html, css, html2pdf

I'm using `HTML2PDF` to generate html into pdf-files, in `php`.
It's when I started creating headers when I came across a problem.

The problem is, the header needs to be 8px of the side. I tried giving it a `margin-left`, `padding-left`, `absolute` `position` `left`, and even tried inline `CSS` but nothing seems to work. The `html2pdf` docs doesn't get me further into solving this problem as well. Here is the code I'm trying to generate:

```
$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'en', true, 'UTF-8', array('0','0','0','0'));
    $html2pdf->pdf->SetAuthor('Author');
    $html2pdf->pdf->SetTitle('title');
    $html2pdf->pdf->SetSubject(PDF);
    $html2pdf->pdf->SetKeywords(' ');

$html = '
<page backimg="background.jpg" backtop="200px" backleft="32px" backbottom="120px">
    <page_header>
        <h1>'.$webpageTitle.'</h1>
    </page_header>
    '.$content.'
</page>';

$html2pdf->writeHTML($html);
$html2pdf->Output('pdf', 'F');
```

To be clear, I can see the header, so there's no problem.
And for those wondering, yes: The `css` is attached.
If any further information is needed, feel free to ask.

I can't place the header inside of the content, because I want the heaer to be visible on every page, not just the first page.

[Documentation](http://wiki.spipu.net/doku.php?id=html2pdf:en:v4:Accueil)

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the content in `<!DOCTYPE html><html><body></body></html>` ?

Comment: `doctype`, `html`, `body` and `head` tags aren't supported by `html2pdf`. Source: http://html2pdf.fr/en/default

Comment: Supported or not they don't break it, I use it on complete rendered pages with no problems - just an idea

Comment: It doesn't crash if I were to leave these tags in. Unfortunately, I'm prety sure they say you can't use these tags for a good reason. Why else would they say you can't use it? The thing is, I can't see how this would help me with the `page_header` tags, since the `content` variable isn't a part of the `page_header`. Don't get me wrong, I appreciate your help, I just want a explanation on how this would work, for the future.

Comment: Another question, have you tried adding the same CSS to the `<h1>` tag instead of `<page_header>`?

Comment: Yes I have. Properties like `font-size`, `padding-top`, `margin-top` and `color` does work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the answer myself.

The thing is, `html2pdf` has more support on `div` tags compared to different tags.
Therefor, I added a div around the `h1` and then gave it a `margin-left` value.

Here is what the code looks like now:

```
$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'en', true, 'UTF-8', array('0','0','0','0'));
    $html2pdf->pdf->SetAuthor('Author');
    $html2pdf->pdf->SetTitle('title');
    $html2pdf->pdf->SetSubject(PDF);
    $html2pdf->pdf->SetKeywords(' ');

$html = '
<page backimg="background.jpg" backtop="200px" backleft="32px" backbottom="120px">
    <page_header>
        <div class="header"><h1>'.$webpageTitle.'</h1></div>
    </page_header>
    '.$content.'
</page>';

$html2pdf->writeHTML($html);
$html2pdf->Output('pdf', 'F');
```

The CSS looks like this:

```
.header {
    padding-left: 8px;
}
```

Feel free to give suggestions on something I've missed or a way to improve my code.

Answer (score 1):

I ve set the margins in the page tag like:

```
<page backtop="24mm" backbottom="20mm"...
```

Hope this helps ;-)

Comment: This doesn't realy help. I haven't put this in my example code, but I have placed it in my script. First of, this only affects the content, not the `<page_header>`. I can't place the header inside the content because I want the header to be visible in every page, not just the first page. Thanks for your help though.